Who こっち refers to here?
In Konosuba ch. 4, a demon king army general was about to give a proposal and someone interrupted him with 迷惑なのはこっちよ.
I initially thought こっち refers to a speaker but I think it actually refers to the general himself. Can こっち refer to the one you are talking to?


こっち always refers to the speaker's side. But 迷惑だ in this context means "(I'm) troubled" or "(it) is a trouble", not "(I'm) causing trouble". This is an ambiguity similar to your previous question.

迷惑なのはこっちよ！
I am the one who's troubled!
(very literally: "It's on this side that it's a trouble!")

